# How to find in a more formal way $\lfloor{(2+\sqrt3)^4}\rfloor$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> The largest integer which is less than or equal to $(2+\sqrt3)^4$ is
>
> $\text{(A)}192\qquad\qquad \text{(B)}193\qquad\qquad \text{(C)}194\qquad\qquad\text{(C)}195\qquad\qquad$

---

**My Solution:-**

I started with the binomial expansion but as I was not able to think of any manipulation which would make my life easier so I just did the following.

$$(2+\sqrt3)^2=\binom{4}{0}2^4+\binom{4}{1}(2^3)(\sqrt3)+\binom{4}{2}(2)^2(\sqrt3)^2+\binom{4}{3}(2)(\sqrt3)^3+\binom{4}{4}(\sqrt3)^4$$

On arranging the integers and the irrational terms separately I ended up with $$(2+\sqrt3)^4=97+56\sqrt3=97+56+56(\sqrt3-1)=153+56(\sqrt3-1)$$

At this point still no manipulation was obvious to me that I can do that would give me answer to $\lfloor{(2+\sqrt3)^4}\rfloor$, so I just used a rough estimate of $(\sqrt3-1)\approx0.732$ to get $56(\sqrt3-1)=40.992$.

The rough estimate of $56(\sqrt3-1)\approx40.992$ is dangerously close to $41$ so at this point I was pretty confused as to how to ascertain that $56(\sqrt3-1)\lt 41$ or $56(\sqrt3-1)\gt 41$, which had left me with the answer as one of the options out of (C) and (D).

Your help is needed for resolving this doubt of mine.

> Also, what would have been a more subjective approach.

Comment: The motivation is based on the fact that if we let $a_n=(2+\sqrt3)^n+(2-\sqrt3)^n$, then this sequence is recursively defined by $a_0=2$, $a_1=4$ and $a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-a_n$ and $a_n$ is an integer "close enough" to $(2+\sqrt3)^n$. This is a standard technique for handling problems like this.

Answer (score 4):

Another way . . .

Let $a = 2 + \sqrt{3},\;\;b = 2 - \sqrt{3}$.

Then

$$a + b = 4$$

$$ab = 1$$

so

$$a^2 + b^2 = (a+b)^2 - 2ab = 4^2-2(1) = 14$$

hence

$$a^4 + b^4 = (a^2 + b^2)^2 - 2(ab)^2 = 14^2 - 2(1)^2 = 194\\[0pt]$$

Then

\begin{align*}
&a^4 + b^4 = 194\\[6pt]
\implies\; &193 < a^4 < 194\qquad\text{[since $0 < b < 1$]}\\[6pt]
\implies\; &\lfloor{a^4}\rfloor=193
\end{align*}

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence: $T_n = (2+\sqrt{3})^n + (2-\sqrt{3})^n$.

Since $(\lambda - (2+\sqrt{3})(\lambda-(2-\sqrt{3})) = \lambda^2 - 4\lambda + 1$, this sequence satisfies a linear recurrence relation:

$$T_{n+2} = 4T_{n+1} - T_{n},\quad \forall n$$
Since $T_0 = 2$ and $T_1 = 4$ are integers, this recurrence relation implies
all $T_n$ are integers.
Look at everything under modulus $4$, we obtain

$$T_4 \equiv -T_2 \equiv T_0 = 2 \pmod 4$$
Since $0 < 2-\sqrt{3} < 1$, we have $0 < (2-\sqrt{3} )^4 < 1$. This leads 
to 
$$\left\lfloor (2+\sqrt{3})^4 \right\rfloor = T_4 - 1 \equiv 1 \pmod 4$$
Among the $4$ given choices, only $193$ has the right remainder when you divide it by $4$.

Comment: The mod trick is nice (given competition time constraints). Alternatively, you can just find the actual value of $T_4$.

Comment: @quasi  I didn't find $T_4$ on purpose. I'm presenting an approach which didn't need the value of $T_4$. The same logic works even when one replace $\left\lfloor (2+\sqrt{3})^4 \right\rfloor$ by monster like $\left\lfloor (2+\sqrt{3})^{4444} \right\rfloor$ ;-)

Comment: I knew that you knew. I was just pointing out for the benefit of the OP, that -- given that it's only $T_4$, the same method you provided gets the exact value of $T_4$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Find

$$(2+\sqrt3)^4 + (2-\sqrt3)^4 $$

(expand and cancel), and note that $0 < (2-\sqrt3) < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know matrix multiplication, here's a fun trick. Arithmetic with $a+b\sqrt{N}$ can be performed as matrix arithmetic, under the representation

$$a+b\sqrt{N} \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a & bN \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}
$$

It's not necessarily any easier but I thought you might find it interesting. (It only works when all Ns are the same. If you have multiple square roots you need a larger matrix to represent all the cross terms.)

Regardless, expanding the power is a fine first step. I got $97+56\sqrt{3}$ same as you. We could bring the $56$ inside as 3136, to get $97 + \sqrt{9408}$. The largest natural number whose square is less than or equal to 9408 is 96. So we have $\sqrt{9408} = \sqrt{96^2 + 192}$. This means, whatever the square root of 9408 is, it's $96 + \delta$ for some $\delta < 1$.

So our answer should be $97+96 = 193$. The actual value is $193.99485\ldots$ so you can see how a poor estimation would give the wrong answer.

Comment: I do know matrix multiplication and this indeed seems very interesting but how did you get $$a+b\sqrt{n} \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a & bN \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$$.

Comment: @user350331 if you work out the arithmetic by hand you can see the correspondence for yourself. Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180849/why-is-the-complex-number-z-abi-equivalent-to-the-matrix-form-left-begins

Comment: Okay this might seem dumb but I think I dont understand what is meant by$$a+b\sqrt{n} \Leftrightarrow \begin{pmatrix} a & bN \\ b & a \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I mean if you multiply the matrix ((a bN)(b a)) by ((c dN)(d c)) you will find that the terms of the first column agree with $(a+b\sqrt{N})(c+d\sqrt{N})$, along with other arithmetic combinations (addition, subtraction, multiplicative inverses, associativity, distributivity...). With respect to arithmetic the matrix represents the number.