# Find closest integer to $(3+\sqrt7)^4$ by hand

Tags: arithmetic, radicals

> Find the closest integer to $$(3+\sqrt7)^4$$ by hand, without knowing the correct value of $\sqrt7$ (Maybe just knowing that $2<\sqrt7<3$).

My work:$$(3+\sqrt7)^4 = (16+6\sqrt7)^2 = 508+192\sqrt7$$

The "influence" of the uncertain $\sqrt7$ is pretty big if we just expand it out. Please help!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2254817/42969 for a very similar question.

Comment: What does it mean to "know the correct value of $\sqrt{7}$"?

Comment: Helps to note that the minimal polynomial of $3+\sqrt 7$ is $x^2-6x+2$, and that the other root is small.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that $2< \sqrt{7}<3$, then you know that $3-\sqrt{7}$ is less than one.  So $(3-\sqrt{7})^4$ is even smaller.  So if you add

$$(3+\sqrt{7})^4 + (3-\sqrt{7})^4$$

you don't change the number by very much, but there are no $\sqrt{7}$'s in the result.

Comment: Related:  $A_n = (3+\sqrt{7})^n + (3-\sqrt{7})^n$ satisfies a second-order linear recurrence with integer coefficients.  Find that recurrence and use it to comute $A_4$.  You may think of this if you know the corresponding thing for  Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Is this essentially different from (e.g.) https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2254856/42969, which was already pointed out as a possible duplicate target?