# Vector operation: add angles, multiply absolue values. How is it called?

Tags: vectors, rotations, associativity

For two complex values, multiplication amounts to adding their polar-representation angles and multiplying their absolute values.

For $\mathbb{R}^n$ I could define the same rule for two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ as $\vec{z} := \vec{x}\curvearrowleft\vec{y}$ such that

\begin{align}
     \operatorname{polarangles}(\vec{z})
  &=   \operatorname{polarangles}(\vec{x})
     + \operatorname{polarangles}(\vec{y})\\
     |\vec{z}|
  &= |\vec{x}| \cdot |\vec{y}|
\end{align}
where $\operatorname{polarangles}(\dots)$ is a tuple of $n-1$ polar coordinate angles.

Since addition and multiplication are commutative and associative, it looks to me as if $\curvearrowleft$ should be too, with the unit vector in $x$ direction ($z$ direction, hmm?) being the neutral element of the operation.

On the other hand the operation contains a rotation which, afaik, is not associative for $n\geq3$. Is it or is it not associative?

Does this operation have a name, is there some theory about it? Or can I have an argument or example showing that it is actually not well defined?

There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2313548/121890), but the answers all focus on different points. Most suggest, though indirectly, that the operation is useless, but without giving arguments (apart from the distinguished direction argument in the top voted answer).

Comment: I think this breaks down for $n>2$ because there is no _canonical_ way of describing a direction as a tuple of angles. Even though one can easily _choose_ such a representation, adding the angles position-for-position would not really be a meaningful operation. (It would not be a rigid movement of the unit (hyper)sphere, or even respect the fact that some angle tuples actually work out to be the same direction).

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what the Frobenius theorem tells me. But it would be great to have an example where it is obvious that adding the angles produces nonsense (even if a modulus of $2\pi$ or $\pi$ is applied as needed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This attactive idea is unfortunately doomed by the Frobenius theorem and even more by [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(composition_algebras)). The latter says, slightly paraphrased, that if you have a binary operation $*$ on $\mathbb R^n$ that satisfies:

- $\|x*y\| = \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$,
- The distributive laws $x*(y+z)=x*y+x*z$ and $(x+y)*z = x*z+y*z$, and
- $(r,0,\ldots,0)*x = x*(r,0,\ldots,0) = r\cdot x$ for every $r\in\mathbb R$

then the $n$ is either $1$, $2$, $4$, or $8$, and the whole thing is isomorphic to either the reals, the complex numbers, the quaternions, or the octonions.

In particular, no matter what you do with the angles, you can't get a solution for $\mathbb R^3$ that distributes over vector addition.

---

What goes wrong in your concrete attempt is that the addition of polar angles is not really well defined. The addition means that you can't restrict the angles to a single interval, so there will be more than one set of angles that represent the same direction, and your componentwise addition does not respect this equivalence.

For example, in $\mathbb R^3$, say we're using longitude and latitude as our polar angles. Then $90^\circ\, E,\; 45^\circ\, N$ is the same place as $90^\circ\, W,\; 135^\circ\, N$ -- but if we add each of these to *itself* then we end up on the north pole in the first case and on the south pole in the second!

We get a similar problem if we use inclination/azimuth coordinates instead.

Note also that adding something to either latitude or azimuth does not correspond to a *rotation* of the unit sphere.

Comment: I would have said that I can live without distributive law for addition, although obviously a pita. But the angle argument is great. Though I could counter that 135°N is not allowed (out of range), but then a 0°W, 46°N added to itself would overflow, would need some modulus and --- and this kills it --- would require to "fix" the 0°W to be flipped to 180°E. Hmm, a bit like a carry bit. Actually all I am after is to solve this  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2893838/121890 to somehow solve this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2890288/121890 (sorry for the plug:-)