# Example of matrix group related to complex numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis, group-theory

Let us take matrices of the form

\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
-b & a
\end{bmatrix}

with $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ not both zero. The determinant $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$. These matrices together with matrix multiplication, form an infinite abelian group. In Herstein's *Topics in Algebra*, he mentions that we should compute the product in this group and write it in the form $aI+bJ$ with $I$ the identity and $J$ being

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

and see if we are reminded of anything. Computing the product gives

\begin{bmatrix}
ac-bd & ad+bc\\
-(ad+bc) & ac-bd
\end{bmatrix}

which can be written as $(ac-bd)I+(ad+bc)J$ and clearly, this is reminiscent of complex number multiplication if we consider multiplying $a+bi$ and $c+di$ as well as their conjugates. But, I'm wondering if there is more to know about this group. I assume I've recognized what Herstein wanted us to recognize but, does this group have a special name and perhaps a special application somewhere? And what significance does it have for complex analysis, if any?

Comment: It's called the multiplicative group of the complex numbers.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/180849/418145

Comment: @PeterMüller but the multiplicative group of the complex numbers is just $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ together with complex multiplication, no? It's doesn't seem to be a matrix group like this one..

Comment: You showed that there is a group isomorphism between them.