# Question(s) regarding complex numbers and representation of quantities in general with matricies.

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers

A complex number is often simply cited to map to specific matricies:

$$
z = a+ib\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}
\text{ where it is the case that } 
1=e_1\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix} ,
i=e_2\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

The response to questions regarding this representation of complex numbers are often met with the answer that it is sufficient that these matrix representations satisfy all the normal field axioms and whatever necessary properties of complex numbers such as associativity and commutativity.

This is fine, and technically true but it is helpful to understand the motivation for creating such representations as well as how it might be done in general.

[Paul Garret states here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180849/why-is-the-complex-number-z-abi-equivalent-to-the-matrix-form-left-begins/180856#comment9512548_180856) that these representations may be made in general by considering how a complex number acts on the 'basis vectors' of $\mathbb{C}$.

$$
1z = e_1*(e_1a+e_2b)=e_1a+e_2b=
\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
\\
iz=e_2*(e_1a+e_2b)=e_2a-e_1b=
\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-b\\a\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}-b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

For the sake of clarity I will specify that row-column matrix product above simple represents a linear combination of the basis $e_1$, $e_2$ with the components of the components $a$, $b$. In this notation, the operation between the matricies is simple matrix multiplication. I included the reversed form since each representation produces the same linear combination.

We may consider both equations at once by considering the tensor product:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\\e_2&-e_1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}e_1a+e_2b\\-e_1b+e_2a\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

**Question**: What is the justification for removing explicit reference to the basis - the $\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\end{pmatrix}^\intercal$ matrix - and making the identification:

$$
a+ib=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}
$$

Below I have constructed a 'proof' to demonstrate my reasoning on the matter, but I feel that I am lacking sufficient justification for the seemingly arbitrary tensor product and commutation of the complex scalar quantity with the basis matrix.

In general scalars commute with matricies, and the tensor product of a column matrix and a row matrix is a well defined matrix multiplication. I am not confident in my understanding. Below is an attempt to algebraically prove that every complex number $z$ has a unique matrix representation.

---

Suppose that $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a scalar quantity and commutes with any given matrix. So potentially we could write:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}z=
\begin{pmatrix}e_1z\\e_2z\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}ze_1\\ze_2\end{pmatrix}=
z\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

From above we have:

$$
z\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then subtract the left side from the right side and factor the basis matrix to obtain:

$$
{\bf 0}
=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
-z\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
=
\left[\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}
-z\right]\begin{pmatrix}e_1\\e_2\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since $\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\end{pmatrix}^\intercal\ne{\bf 0}$ then it must be the case that:

$$
0=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}
-z
\Rightarrow
z=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\-b&a\end{pmatrix}
$$

---

Obviously the above is not a completely rigorous proof, but I was trying to fill in missing details from resources I lack and books I have not yet read.

Comment: There is a lot going on here, can you state your question in a sentence? I don’t believe what is written under the bolded question is the actual problem

Comment: @KevinS, I understand. I guess I can boil my question to "Is the method by which such matrix representations are made really this simple?"

Comment: @KevinS, I would like to clarify that the 'proof' I provided was my attempt to deduce and derive a 'yes, it really is that simple' answer. I don't feel my proof is wrong, and it seems to make sense, but I know that if I was to publish this as a 'proof' then it must be completely rewritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Representation Theory, one is interested in giving a correspondence:
$$g\in G \leftrightarrow [\rho(g)]_{\beta}$$
between *group elements* and *matrices* (or linear operators in the absence of a basis).
This is done in such a way as to preserve the structure of the group (i.e. we make $\rho:G\to GL_n(V/F)$ a *group-homomorphism*). Alternatively, one may construct a *group action*:
$$\theta: G\times V\to V$$
$$(g,v)\mapsto \theta(g,v)$$
that gives rise to the desired hom in the obvious way:
$$\forall v\in V,\text{ }\text{ }\rho(g)v:= \theta(g,v).$$
When there is more structure involved (say field structure), one can require $\rho$ to be a *field-homomorphism* instead to make sure things play nicely in the image.

---

Now, if we take $G:= \mathbb{C}$ and $V/F:= \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$. We may give the values for the action $\theta$ as you have partially done above in the post.
Whereas for *finite* groups, we may list $\theta$ quickly by defining the action of *conjugacy class representatives* (e.g. cycle types for $G:= S_n$), complex multiplication is commutative, so each element defines its own conjugacy class (and hence is not theoretically useful here). Instead, we have the basis, $\beta:= \{1,i\}$, at our disposal. We define the actions of $1$ and $i$ (from $G$) on $1$ and $i$ (from $V$):
$$\theta(1,1) := 1$$
$$\theta(1,i) := i$$
$$\theta(i,1) := i$$
$$\theta(i,i) := -1$$
and *extend by linearity in both variables* to get the desired $\theta$.
Then since $\rho(g)v = \theta(g,v)$, it should be clear with linear algebra intuition, that:
$$\big[\rho(\color{blue}{a+bi})\big]_{\beta}[v]_{\beta} = \color{blue}{\begin{bmatrix}a&& -b\\ b&& a\end{bmatrix}}[v]_{\beta}$$

---

To elaborate a little:
(1) Matrix representations for linear operators (a.k.a. transformations $T$) are given by listing the coordinate reps for its images of basis vectors--which here looks like: $$[T]_{\beta} = \bigg[[Te_1]_{\beta}\text{ }\text{ }[Te_2]_{\beta}\bigg].$$
(2) It should be further noted that $\theta$ satisfies:
$$\theta(1,v) = v$$
$$\theta(g,\theta(h,v)) = \theta(gh,v)$$
so that it is a group action. The second line says complex multiplication is associative.

---

The point of this answer was to phrase things in terms of Representation Theory so that the motivation is more clear. The actual construction of $\theta$ here is straight forward, but things complicate when you define other actions where $V$ is different.

Comment: I want to say, it took me a few days to fully understand everything you are saying and few others have been able to explain something so well. I appreciate the effort that you put into this answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just to clarify,  $V/F:= \mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is the set of complex numbers without the the set of real numbers: all complex numbers with non-zero imaginary components? In principle I don't see why this is necessary.

Comment: Is $V$ supposed to correspond to the set that contains $v=\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\end{pmatrix}^\intercal$ as an element? If so then $\theta(g,v)\in V$ and $\theta(z,v)=\begin{pmatrix}e_1&e_2\end{pmatrix}^\intercal z$ for $z\in \mathbb{C}$, correct?

Comment: In simple terms, if I were to tell someone who doesn't know much of this material yet, $\rho(z)$ essentially just means "to make the matrix representation of z"?

Comment: So the $V/F$ notation means vector space over a field. So $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ is intended to mean the complex numbers as a real vector space. For example: $z = a1+bi$ is a linear combination of the basis $\beta$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. When the scalar field is understood, we can omit reference to it, displaying only $V$. As for the "rho" symbol, $\rho$, this is common for "representation" map. It is the function sending $z$ to its matrix rep as you said.

Comment: "The Symmetric Group" by Bruce Sagan is a good reference for more of this type of thing!

Comment: I read $V/F$ that way first, but I've seen too many different notations to not ask. Thank you very much!